# Cannot Convert Map<string, class> Value in Assignment

Tags: c++, dictionary

I have an assignment I am working on that I've hit the following error on and can't fix. Can someone explain this error and give possible solutions for fixing it? The last night of code is where the error is occurring. Any insight would be appreciated.

81:43: error: cannot convert 'album' to 'std::map, album*>::mapped_type {aka album*}' in assignment

```
class song {
    public:
        string title;
        int time;
        int track;

};

class album{
    public:
        map <int, song *> songs;
        string name;
        int time;
};

class artist{
    public:
        map <string, album *> albums;
        string name;
        int time;
        int nsongs;
};

int main (int argc, char* argv[]){
    song song;
    album album;
    artist artist;
    const string file = argv[1];
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open(file.c_str());
    int itime;
    int secs, mins, hours;
    char extra;
    string stitle, stime, sartist, salbum, sgenre, strack;
    stringstream ss;

    if(infile.fail()){
        cerr << "Could not open file" << endl;
        exit (1);
    }

    while (infile >> stitle >> stime >> sartist >> salbum >> sgenre >> strack){
        replace(stitle.begin(), stitle.end(), '_', ' ');
        song.title = stitle;
        ss << stime;
        ss >> mins >> extra >> secs;
        itime = (mins * 60) + secs;
        ss.str("");
        ss.clear();
        mins = itime/60;
        secs = itime%60;
        song.time = itime;

        song.track = atoi (strack.c_str());
        replace(salbum.begin(), salbum.end(), '_', ' ');
        album.name = salbum;

        replace(sartist.begin(), sartist.end(), '_', ' ');
        artist.name = sartist;
        if(artist.albums.count(artist.name)  == 1){
            cout << "Old Artist: " << artist.name << endl;
            cout << "New Artist: " << artist.name << endl;
        }
        else{artist.albums[artist.name] = album;}
```

Comment: Since i see no inhertance between objects, cant you use references in maps instead of pointers ? Then you will not have any troubles with memory allocation and you can remove pointers from maps (and code should work)

Comment: Just a warning. variables with the same id as types is a **bad** idea. Things like `album album;` and `song song;` and `artist artist;`makes the forthcoming code difficult to read and extremely prone to subtle bugs.

Comment: Yes, I plan on changing the variable names.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to assign an 'album' object to a pointer of type 'album', assuming you have a valid pointer to allocated memory, you could write something like

```
else{*(artist.albums[artist.name]) = album;}
```

since I don't see any memory allocation for the pointer you'll have to allocate memory yourself before inserting stuff into the map, e.g.

```
else{artist.albums[artist.name] = new album();}
```

and **remember to free this memory at the end of your program**

Comment: I think if the OP really insists on using pointers (which he or she probably should not), then a `std::shared_ptr` may actually be desirable, so that the classes themselves can still be used as value types. I.e. `std::map<int, std::shared_ptr<song>>` and so on. But still, it does not look like pointers are needed here at all.

Comment: I agree on the shared pointers but that might be the second step. Understanding OP's problem is the first step.

Comment: Perhaps the background of his question is unfounded fear of performance problems when not using pointers, or a Java background where everything but primitives is pointers.

Answer (score 0):

There is no apparent reason to use **pointers**. Just write:

```
class song {
    public:
        string title;
        int time;
        int track;

};

class album{
    public:
        map <int, song> songs;
        string name;
        int time;
};

class artist{
    public:
        map <string, album> albums;
        string name;
        int time;
        int nsongs;
};
```

`song`, `album` (and `artist`) all look like **value classes**. Which means that individual objects do not have identity, and objects can be compared for equality. Such classes are not typically used with pointers.

`std::string` itself is another (very typical) example of a value class. You do not usually store pointers to strings or pass or return string pointers. You will rarely see something like `std::map<int, std::string*>`, `std::list<std::string*>`, `f(std::string* s)` or `std::string* f()`.

In fact, `int` itself is a value type as well. There's a reason why something like `std::map<int, int*>`, `std::list<int*>`, `f(int* i)` or `int* f()` looks suspicious.

As far as your code is concerned, songs, albums and artists are like strings and ints.

---

There are a couple of other problems with your code, by the way:

```
int itime;
```

This looks like Microsoft-style Hungarian Notation, which I like to call a failed experiment from the 90s. Just call the variable `time`.

```
string stitle, stime, sartist, salbum, sgenre, strack;
```

Same here. If you need two variables of the same name with different types (which should not happen very often), be explicit about it and call them something like `time_as_integer` and `time_as_string`.

```
while (infile >> stitle >> stime >> sartist >> salbum >> sgenre >> strack)
```

What will this loop do if one of the titles happens to be *"Let it be"*? You need a more robust mechanism. Read entire lines with `std::getline` and use something like Boost Tokenizer to split them.

```
atoi (strack.c_str());
```

`atoi` cannot distinguish between `"0"` and invalid input like `""` or `"a"`. It will return 0 in any case. Use string streams or C++11 `stoi`.

---

P.S.: Please post compilable code. In order to reproduce your error, one has to manually add all of the following, which is very tedious:

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <map>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std; // just for throwaway test code
```

You also have to add

```
    }
}
```

at the end of the code.

Even with those modifications, your code does not reach 81 lines.

Comment: May I ask the downvoter to explain what's wrong with this answer?

Comment: Thanks for you tips. The strack portion of the file (the ones that he tests with) are all actual numbers. My prof gives us the testing files ahead of time to test ourselves with them before turning them in. I will probably end up using getline, but all the titles with multiple words are separated with '_' between words instead of whitespace. Thank you for all comments. This was my first time posting a question so I appreciate the helpful feedback.